# Items in checklistbox deleted after form closes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple c# winform and I'm trying to add a string to it.
e.g.

```
checklistbox1.Items.Add("string");
```

the problem is that after I close the form and run the program again, my added string is deleted from the checklistbox and I have to enter it again.

Comment: Where did you write this code?

Comment: this line of code is in a button.

Comment: You are probably creating a new instance of the form each time you open it.

Comment: If you want to save the string that you add, you need to save it somewhere. This line of code adds the string to an object that will be garbage collected when the program ends.

Comment: A CheckListBox doesn't save for you its contents. Once the form is destroyed (and its control with it) the Items are gone. You need to provide a way to save and reload the content of the listbox

Answer (score 0):

When you close the form, the members associated with it are removed as well. If you want it to be saved, you need to use a method that well save the data for you, such as XML, txt doc, or even a database, depending on the lifespan of the information you want to keep.

If it is only needed while the program is running, you may look into having the information stored in a member in the mainform rather than only just the form with the checklistbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public List property to your form.
Create a second ctor for your form and inside your second ctor code
write:

```
public YourForm(List<string>() strings)
{
     foreach(var item in strings)
     {
        checklistbox1.Items.Add(item);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to unload the form when closing. Let the parent form - I assume this is launched from another form - do the unloading/disposing of all the child forms instead. The trick is to make it appear to the user that you're closing the form. Let's say the form containing the checklist is Form2, the function that loads Form2 from the parent form will look like this:

```
    Form2 _form2 = null;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_form2 == null)
        {
            _form2 = new Form2();
        }

        _form2.Show();
    }
```

And in the Form2, handle the Closing event like this:
        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
        }

And finally, in the parent form Closing event, you can dispose Form2

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_form2 != null)
        {
            _form2.Dispose();
            _form2 = null;
        }
    }
```

If you need to have the same set of values for all instances of Form2, then you can use Singleton pattern. That's another discussion :)

Comment: Oops sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. This is actually just the main form I suppose. My post doesn't answer the question then. The only way is to persist it somewhere - this is where persistence mechanism is all about. You have choices like file system using plain text or xml, database or registry